# No data is being loaded when reading tfrecord files

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am trying to train the model defined [here](https://github.com/andrewowens/multisensory/blob/master/src/shift_net.py) using the function `train` defined in the same script. I have attempted to use a tf record file provided by the authors in [this link](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~owens/multisensory/sep_example.tf) (to do that, the only modifications that I made were changing `init_path=None` and writing the path to the tfrecord file in the txt file `train_list=train_tfs.txt`, both defined in `shift_params.py`'s `shift_v1` ).

However, even trying this simple test, I get the following error:

```
OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch_join/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 15, current size 0)
         [[Node: shuffle_batch_join = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shuffle_batch_join/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch_join/n)]]
```

As far as I understand, this error means that no data is being loaded. So my guess is that the problem is in the function `read_example` in `shift_dset.py`, as shown below (I have kept only the part of the code that loads the images `ims` and the audio `sound`. For the complete code, please check [here](https://github.com/andrewowens/multisensory/blob/master/src/shift_dset.py).)

```
def read_example(rec_queue, pr, input_types):
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
  k, serialized_example = reader.read(rec_queue)
  full = pr.full_im_dim

  feats = {}

  feats['im_0'] = tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string)
  feats['im_1'] = tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string)

  feats['sound'] = tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string)

  if pr.variable_frame_count:
    feats['num_frames'] = tf.FixedLenFeature([1], dtype=tf.int64)
  example = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features = feats)

  total_frames = pr.total_frames if not pr.variable_frame_count \
                 else tf.cast(example['num_frames'][0], tf.int32)

  assert not pr.variable_frame_count

  def f(x):
    x.set_shape((full*total_frames/2, full, 3))
    return tf.reshape(x, (total_frames/2, full, full, 3))
  im_parts = map(f, [tf.image.decode_jpeg(example['im_0'], channels = 3, name = 'decode_im1'),
                     tf.image.decode_jpeg(example['im_1'], channels = 3, name = 'decode_im2')])

  samples = tf.decode_raw(example['sound'], tf.int16)

  samples.set_shape((pr.full_samples_len*2))
  samples = tf.reshape(samples, (pr.full_samples_len, 2))

  samples = tf.cast(samples, 'float32') / np.iinfo(np.dtype(np.int16)).max


  num_slice_frames = pr.sampled_frames
  num_samples = int(pr.samples_per_frame * float(num_slice_frames))

  if pr.do_shift:
    choices = []
    max_frame = total_frames - num_slice_frames
    frames1 = ([0] if pr.fix_frame else xrange(max_frame))
    for frame1 in frames1:
      found = False
      for frame2 in reversed(range(max_frame)):
        inv1 = xrange(frame1, frame1 + num_slice_frames)
        inv2 = xrange(frame2, frame2 + num_slice_frames)
        if len(set(inv1).intersection(inv2)) <= pr.max_intersection:
          found = True
          choices.append([frame1, frame2])
          if pr.fix_frame:
            break
      if pr.skip_notfound:
        pass
      else:
        assert found
    print 'Number of frame choices:', len(choices)
    choices = tf.constant(np.array(choices), dtype = tf.int32)
    idx = tf.random_uniform([1], 0, shape(choices, 0), dtype = tf.int64)[0]
    start_frame_gt = choices[idx, 0]
    shift_frame = choices[idx, 1]
  elif ut.hastrue(pr, 'use_first_frame'):
    shift_frame = start_frame_gt = tf.constant(0, dtype = tf.int32)
  else:
    shift_frame = start_frame_gt = tf.random_uniform(
      [1], 0, total_frames - num_slice_frames, dtype = tf.int32)[0]

  if pr.augment_ims:
    print 'Augment:', pr.augment_ims
    r = tf.random_uniform(
      [2], 0, pr.full_im_dim - pr.crop_im_dim, dtype = tf.int32)
    x, y = r[0], r[1]
  else:
    if hasattr(pr, 'resize_dims'):
      y = pr.resize_dims[0]/2 - pr.crop_im_dim/2
      x = pr.resize_dims[1]/2 - pr.crop_im_dim/2
    else:
      y = x = pr.full_im_dim/2 - pr.crop_im_dim/2

  offset = [start_frame_gt, y, x, 0]
  d = pr.crop_im_dim
  size_im = [num_slice_frames, d, d, 3]


  slice_parts = []
  for j in xrange(len(im_parts)):
    num_frames_in_part = total_frames/len(im_parts)

    part_start = j*num_frames_in_part
    frame_offset = tf.maximum(0, tf.minimum(start_frame_gt - part_start, num_frames_in_part))
    end_offset = tf.maximum(0, tf.minimum(start_frame_gt + num_slice_frames - part_start, num_frames_in_part))
    num_frames_in_part_slice = tf.maximum(0, end_offset - frame_offset)

    offset = [frame_offset, y, x, 0]
    d = pr.crop_im_dim

    size_im = [num_frames_in_part_slice, d, d, 3]
    p = tf.slice(im_parts[j], offset, size_im)
    slice_parts.append(p)
  ims_slice = tf.concat(slice_parts, 0)
  ims_slice.set_shape([num_slice_frames, pr.crop_im_dim, pr.crop_im_dim, 3])
  ims = ims_slice

  if pr.augment_ims:
    ims = tf.cond(tf.cast(tf.random_uniform([1], 0, 2, dtype = tf.int64)[0], tf.bool),
                  lambda : tf.map_fn(tf.image.flip_left_right, ims), 
                  lambda : ims)

  def slice_samples(frame):
    start = round_int(pr.samples_per_frame * cast_float(frame))
    offset = [start, 0]
    size = [num_samples, 2]
    r = tf.slice(samples, offset, size, name = 'slice_sample')
    r.set_shape([num_samples] + list(shape(r)[1:]))
    return r

  if 'samples' in input_types:
    samples_gt = slice_samples(start_frame_gt)
    samples_shift = slice_samples(shift_frame)
  else:
    samples_gt = samples_shift = tf.zeros((1, 1), dtype = tf.int16)  

  samples_exs = tf.concat([ed(samples_shift, 0), ed(samples_gt, 0)], 0)


  return ims, _, samples_exs, _, _, _
```

I also tried loading my own tfrecords by changing this function and I got a similar error. Also, when no tfrecord paths are provided (i.e., `train_list=train_tfs.txt` does not contain a path to a tfrecord, thus it is impossible to load anything), I get the same error, which indicates that something is wrong with the way the data is being loaded.

Thank you in advance for any help.

**How to reproduce the same test**

1. Clone the code in [here](https://github.com/andrewowens/multisensory/blob/master/src/shift_net.py)
2. Download the data sample in [here](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~owens/multisensory/sep_example.tf)
3. Change the parameters in `shift_v1` of `shift_params.py`:
   `init_path=None` and the content of `train_tfs.txt` (it should
   contain the path to the downloaded tf file)
4. From the folder `src`, run the following command:

   python -c "import shift_params, shift_net; shift_net.train(shift_params.shift_v1(num_gpus=3), [0, 1, 2], restore = False)"

**Environment details**

I am using the following packages in an anaconda environment (Linux):

- Python 2.7.18
- tensorflow, tensorflow-gpu and tensorflow-base 1.9.0
- numpy, matplotlib, pillow and scipy

Comment: please don't link you your code, but include the relevant part of it in your question

Comment: @Gal Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited my issue by adding the part of the code that I think it's responsible for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, so I am posting the solution that I have found here in case somebody else faces the same problem.

I have not managed to run the data loading code with the tfrecord provided (as presented in the question), so I created my own data loading function to substitute `read_example`, which I post here for further reference:

```
def new_read_example(rec_queue, pr, input_types):
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
  k, serialized_example = reader.read(rec_queue)
  full = pr.full_im_dim # full frame dimension

  feature_description = {
      'video':tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      'sync_audio':tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      'shift_audio':tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      'label':tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
      'num_frames': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64)
  }

  # parse one example
  example = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, feature_description)

  # get label and other variables
  label = tf.cast(example['label'], tf.int64)

  # I could not transform the total_frames from tensor to an integer
  # so I just assigned 100 to total_frames,
  # which is the number of frames that I use
  # total_frames = tf.cast(example['num_frames'], tf.int64)
  total_frames = 100

  ims = tf.image.decode_jpeg(example['video'], channels=3)
  ims.set_shape((full*total_frames, full, 3))
  ims = tf.reshape(ims, (total_frames, full, full, 3))

  # The audio stored in the tfrecords is an array of floats
  # which is encoded as binary by calling audio.tostring()
  sync_audio = tf.decode_raw(example['sync_audio'], tf.float32)
  shift_audio = tf.decode_raw(example['shift_audio'], tf.float32)

  # The audio that I am reading is mono, so I had to change the
  # dimension of the audio data
  sync_audio.set_shape((pr.full_samples_len))
  sync_audio = tf.reshape(sync_audio, (pr.full_samples_len, 1))

  shift_audio.set_shape((pr.full_samples_len))
  shift_audio = tf.reshape(shift_audio, (pr.full_samples_len, 1))

  samples_exs = tf.concat([ed(shift_audio, 0), ed(sync_audio, 0)], 0)

  return ims, samples_exs
```

The conclusion that I take from here is that it is almost impossible to read a tfrecord without knowing exactly how it was created (the best is to have the code that generated the tfrecords) and, in my case, it was easier to write my own pair of tfrecords writer and reader.